# Android Device Monitor not found JDK Path

Tags: java, android-studio, gnome, archlinux

I'm using Arch Linux with Gnome.

I open Android Studio by the desktop item. The code editor works fine, the device manager starts correctly and the app run like a charm, but when I try to open the Device Monitor, I get this error:

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
>   must be available in order to run Monitor. No Java virtual machine
>   was found after searching the following locations:
>   /home/grams/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/jre/bin/java
>   java in your current PATH
>   When i run the android studion from command line, the Device Monitor works.

Here is the .desktop content

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/home/grams/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Name[en_US]=Android Studio
Exec=/home/grams/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
Comment[en_US]=Android Studio IDE
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio IDE
Icon=/home/grams/android-studio/bin/studio.png
```

My JRE and JDK variables are being added on /etc/profile. 
When i run Android Studio on the command line, this error not occurs. Maybe it is a problem with Gnome launcher ?

Comment: Have you set JDK path in your Android Studio? just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, i do. Maybe it is a problem with Gnome launcher?

Comment: I couldn't say more about gnome launcher. I'm only use kde and openbox.

Answer (score 3):

Newest Android Studio Bundle comes with its own JRE (under `<ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre` and this is the recommended JRE to work with (look at File / Project Structure / SDK Location).

Likewise, a simple option is to create a symbolic link under the monitor tools to keep JRE in line with Android Studio even getting an update.

For MAC or Linux:

```
#ln -s <ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre <SDK>/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/jre
```

32 bits:

```
#ln -s <ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre <SDK>/tools/lib/monitor-x86/jre
```

Then the ddms monitor works for both ways:  from Studio IDE (Tools / Android / ADM) or command line  (`<SDK>tools/./monitor`)

Comment: Wherever there is a <ANDROID_STUDIO> and a <SDK> remember to use the full path.

Answer (score 1):

Define your environment variables in the initialization file for your login shell: most likely **.profile** or **.bash_profile**, depending on your setup. Something like:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_05"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

Read more at: [where should i manually install JDK8?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180119) and [JDK installation on Archlinux](http://www.wbprime.me/2015/05/25/JDK-installation-on-Archlinux/)

Answer (score 1):

Please add the location of the folder containing javaw.exe to the System PATH Environment Variable:
e.g PATH = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin"

Comment: OP speak about Linux based system but this answer is for Windows based system

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that the variables deceleration naming convention is according to the rules, and the Android Studio is searching by the names, that are predefined.
As in Windows, the Variable that contains JDK path should named: *JAVA_HOME*
Explore the rules.

Comment: Yes, I have set JAVA_HOME, JAVA_JDK to jdk path, and the PATH has the bin files working properly, i can run 'java -version' and 'javac -version'. I think this problem is because of the .desktop that GNOME use to run the program.
/home/grams/Android/Sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/ is where the monitor bin file is located, and /jre/bin/java doesn't make sense, the java bin files are located in /usr/local/jdk